# Removing Hyper link from an email text using google apps script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I have parsed an email that contains the address, but this address is hyperlinked to google maps. That's why I am not getting the required results.

Here is an example image:

[image]

Can we remove the link from this address and make it simple text? Thank you.

The output which I get due to this is:

> address: 'a href="https:  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) maps search
> 124+Tirzah+St+LEBANON+,++TN+37087+United+States?entry=gmail&source=g" target="_blank"124 Tirzah St

Instead, I am looking for this output:

> 124 Tirzah St LEBANON,TN 37087 United States

Thank you

Comment: You need to give us the actual HTML output. Your output doesn't have the normal format for google maps e.g. `<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/124+Tirzah....>...</a>`

Comment: I cannot understand the relationship between your sample image and the value of `The output which I get due to this is:`. In your situation, there is a HTML data, and you want to retrieve the text data from the HTML data. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`address:.*search (.*)\?`

Javascript:

```
console.log("address: 'a href=\"https: www.google.com maps search 124+Tirzah+St+LEBANON+,++TN+37087+United+States?entry=gmail&source=g\" target=\"_blank\"124 Tirzah St\";".match(/address:.*search (.*)\?/gm));
```

Tested on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

[image]

Comment: No Sir, it is just showing the same output.